# Replace a text by incrementing each occurence

Tags: c#, .net, regex, substring

I have a text say:

```
Hello
abc
Hello
def
Hello
```

I want to convert it to

```
Hello1
abc
Hello2
abc
Hello3
```

i.e I need to append a number after each occurrence of "Hello" text.

Currently I have written this code:

```
var xx = File.ReadAllText("D:\\test.txt");


var regex = new Regex("Hello", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = regex.Matches(xx);


int i = 1;
foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    string yy = match.Value;
    xx = Replace(xx, match.Index, match.Length, match.Value + (i++));
}
```

and the Replace method above used is:

```
public static string Replace(string s, int index, int length, string replacement)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append(s.Substring(0, index));
    builder.Append(replacement);
    builder.Append(s.Substring(index + length));
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Currently the above code is not working and is replacing the text in between.

Can you help me fixing that?

Comment: Wiktor's answer is the best solution. The reason your replace logic isn't working though is that on each iteration of your foreach the index values of the matches go out of date because xx has changed. If you must write a Replace method it seems like it would have be recursive.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming `Hello` is just a placeholder for a more complex pattern, here is a simple fix: use a match evaluator inside `Regex.Replace` where you may use variables:

```
var s = "Hello\nabc\nHello\ndef\nHello";
var i = 0;
var result = Regex.Replace(
    s, "Hello", m => string.Format("{0}{1}",m.Value,++i), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/CptLDz)

Comment: I have a question, Is there any specific reason not use `string.Format()` immediately?

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately"?

Comment: My bad I tought he only needed 3, that was silly because he doesn't even need `string.Format` in that case.